# Select newest data from id A

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, greatest-n-per-group

I have the data like this:

```
ID  TRANS_ID  CREATED_DATE             STATUS
----------------------------------------------
1   AA        2017-05-19 02:00:00      WAITING
2   AA        2017-05-20 02:00:00      IN_PROCESS
3   BB        2017-05-19 02:00:00      WAITING
4   CC        2017-05-19 02:00:00      WAITING
5   CC        2017-05-20 02:00:00      IN_PROCESS
```

I would like to show the data in table view like this one :

```
ID  TRANS_ID  CREATED_DATE             STATUS
----------------------------------------------
2   AA        2017-05-20 02:00:00      IN_PROCESS
3   BB        2017-05-19 02:00:00      WAITING
5   CC        2017-05-20 02:00:00      IN_PROCESS
```

I take the newest data from each `trans_id` and I run this query but it does not work

```
select id, max(created_date), trans_id, status
from table_a
group by a.transaction_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.created_date = (
    select max(t1.created_date) from mytable t1 where t1.trans_id = t.trans_id
)
```

Alternatively, you can use window functions:

```
select id, trans_id, created_date, status
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by trans_id order by created_date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

This allows top ties, if any. If you want no ties, you can use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.